# View logs for nix-env last installation

Tags: software-installation, logs, nixos, nix

I use [NixOS](http://nixos.org/):

```
$ nixos-version 
16.03pre71289.7ae05ed (Emu)
$ nix-env --version
nix-env (Nix) 1.10
$ nix-channel --list

$ sudo nix-channel --list
nixos https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-unstable
```

Installing something through `nix-env` outputs information, like:

```
$ nix-env -i rogue
installing ‘rogue-5.4.4’
these paths will be fetched (0.09 MiB download, 0.28 MiB unpacked):
  /nix/store/rvkjrq24fy510m9dwd12lhry1zkx57iy-rogue-5.4.4
fetching path ‘/nix/store/rvkjrq24fy510m9dwd12lhry1zkx57iy-rogue-5.4.4’...

*** Downloading ‘https://cache.nixos.org/nar/0jpxvn40r27zz9pz54kvfrsy2lwafysbpr6pkhkafizzxqgb2a0c.nar.xz’ (signed by ‘cache.nixos.org-1’) to ‘/nix/store/rvkjrq24fy510m9dwd12lhry1zkx57iy-rogue-5.4.4’...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 95184  100 95184    0     0   104k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  104k

building path(s) ‘/nix/store/y8z7yi655sslnmx4b7zb1vaqp49ac8i6-user-environment’
created 839 symlinks in user environment
```

Reading [Nix manual](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/) suggested `nix-store` command, but I'm not sure how to use it.

How do I view logs of what I ever installed through `nix-env`? How do I view logs of what I ever installed through `sudo nixos-rebuild switch`?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell nix has no log. I'm guessing the reason for excluding this feature of every-other-package-manager-ever is that nixos is declarative rather than imperative, so the process it went through to get your system from one state to another *should be* irrelevant.

Which brings us to what I suspect you really want to know: **How can I compare the current generation with the last?**

I've found [nixos-scripts](https://github.com/matthiasbeyer/nixos-scripts)' `diff-generations` command very helpful for this. For instance, if you're on generation 115, you can get a diff of installed packages with:

```
nix-script diff-generations -s -n 114..115
```